# UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition Not Finishing Animation

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift3

I have a Navigation pop attached to a pan gesture that should interactively pop according to the pan.

### What Works

Transition listens to pan gesture and updates properly

### What Doesn't Work

When the pan gesture is 'ended' or 'canceled'', transition does not complete rest of the animation.  It just snaps to completion without animation.

FirstViewController:

```
extension FirstViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        if operation == .push {
            myInteractionController.attachToViewControllers(fromVc: fromVC, toVc: toVC)
            return myPushTransition
        }
        return myPopTransition
    }


    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, interactionControllerFor animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return myInteractionController.transitionInProgress ? myInteractionController : nil
    }
}
```

MyPopTransition:

```
class MyPopTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, CAAnimationDelegate {
        var initialFrame           : CGRect  = CGRect.zero
        var initialCenter          : CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
        var transitionContext      : UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.8
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        self.transitionContext = transitionContext
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) as! myFirstViewController
        let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as! mySecondViewController
        let fromVC2 = (fromVC.viewControllers![0] as! myThirdViewController)

        containerView.insertSubview(toVC.view, belowSubview: fromVC.view)

        toVC.view.alpha = 1
        fromVC.view.alpha = 1

        fromVC2.addImageViewLayerMask()
        let cropAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        cropAnimation.delegate = self
        cropAnimation.fromValue = UIBezierPath(rect: fromVC2.imageFrame(percentage: 0)).cgPath
        cropAnimation.toValue = UIBezierPath(rect: fromVC2.imageFrame(percentage: 1)).cgPath
        cropAnimation.duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        fromVC2.imageViewMaskLayer!.path = UIBezierPath(rect: fromVC2.imageFrame(percentage: 1)).cgPath
        fromVC2.imageViewMaskLayer!.add(cropAnimation, forKey: "cropAnimation")


        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
                       animations: {
                        let initialScale = self.initialFrame.height <  self.initialFrame.height ?
                            self.initialFrame.height/fromVC.view.bounds.height :
                            self.initialFrame.width/fromVC.view.bounds.width
                        fromVC2.imageView.transform = toVC.view.transform.scaledBy(x: initialScale, y: initialScale)
                        fromVC2.view.center =  self.initialCenter
        },  completion: {
            finished in

        })

    }

    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        if let transitionContext = self.transitionContext {
            if (transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled) {
                transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)?.view.removeFromSuperview()
                ((transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as! mySecondViewController).viewControllers![0] as! myThirdViewController).removeImageViewLayerMask()
                (transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as! mySecondViewController).pageScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
            } else {
                 transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)?.view!.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        }
    }
}
```

MyInteractionController:

```
class MyInteractionController: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition {
        var navigationController        : UINavigationController!
        var fromViewController          : UIViewController?
        var toViewController            : UIViewController?
        var panGestureRecognizer        : UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        var shouldCompleteTransition    = false
        var transitionInProgress        = false

    func attachToViewControllers(fromVc: UIViewController, toVc: UIViewController) {
        navigationController = toVc.navigationController
        self.fromViewController = fromVc
        self.toViewController = toVc
        self.setupGestureRecognizer()
        self.wantsInteractiveStart = true
    }


    private func setupGestureRecognizer() {
        panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        panGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handlePanGesture(gestureRecognizer:)))
        navigationController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

        guard let interactivePopGestureRecognizer = navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer
            else { return }
        panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: interactivePopGestureRecognizer)
    }


    func handlePanGesture(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        var progress = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: gestureRecognizer.view!).y / (gestureRecognizer.view!.bounds.size.height * 0.5)
        progress = min(1.0, max(0.0, progress))

        switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .began:
            transitionInProgress = true
            navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)

        case .changed:
                self.update(progress)

        case .cancelled, .ended:
            transitionInProgress = false
                self.finish()

        default:
            break
        }
    }

}

extension MyInteractionController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer == self.panGestureRecognizer {
            let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: panGestureRecognizer.view)
            let translationIsVertical = (translation.y > 0) && (abs(translation.y) > abs(translation.x))
            return translationIsVertical &&
                (navigationController?.viewControllers.count ?? 0 > 1)
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the main reasons I didn't do view property animator is because, I have to animate layer mask, which I believe I can only do it via CABasicAnimation ?

Comment: I'm just trying to 'pop' viewcontroller interactively with a pan down gesture.

Comment: Still, wouldn't it be the same thing when it comes to handling the pan gesture ?  Above code works without fault when popped from back button, or even during panning. Just doesn't animate the left over when pan ends.

Comment: OK, sorry I wasn't any help. All my code has replaced UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition with UIViewPropertyAnimator in iOS 10 so I don't have a Swift 3 example of UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition. But I'll try to translate an older example into Swift 3 and post it for you to look at.

Comment: OK, here it is: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/61f0c753a080040e4a74b912e6c18dd97fe8bcaa/bk2ch06p296customAnimation2/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.swift You can download and run the example project. Note that it is not identical to what you're doing: it's not a navigation controller, but a tab view controller where you slide the view from the screen edge sideways. But the principle should be exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks.  Great sample code!  Trying to adopt this approach....

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if there turns out to be some reason why it can't work in your case...

Comment: I was successful in going UIViewPropertyAnimator route using your link.  Great work!

Comment: Wow, that's great. Thanks for reporting back. Do we know any more about what was "wrong" with what you were doing? (Not that it matters! If the problem is solved, it's solved.)

Comment: I guess above code's transition animation gets canceled some how. I just followed your sample and Apple's PhotosTransitioning' sample code. Everything is smooth, except.. UIView's Mask View seem to make the animation sluggish. Looking for ways to tweak that. UIViewPropertyAnimator seem to be amazing and I was lucky that My project is only 10.0 or later ..

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, as a possible solution, I ran into this problem on iOS 9, though strangely it worked on iOS 10+.  I was able to fix it by implementing completionSpeed and completionCurve in my UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition subclass:

```
-(CGFloat)completionSpeed {
  return 1.0;
}

-(UIViewAnimationCurve)completionCurve {
  return UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut;
}
```

In fact, you probably don't even need to completionCurve override.  The issue was that [super completionSpeed] was returning 0.  I guess this is the default behavior in some circumstances with UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition on older versions of iOS.